# polynomials satisfying the Plucker relation

Tags: abstract-algebra

Let $S_{12}$, $S_{13}$, $S_{14}$, $S_{23}$, $S_{23}$, $S_{34}$ be complex homogeneous polynomials in 4 variables satisfying the Plucker relation :
$$S_{12}S_{34}-S_{13}S_{24}+S_{14}S_{23}=0 .$$
Suppose also that they don't have any common non trivial zero. Let $d_{ij}=\deg(S_{ij})$. Let $d$ be the integer
$$d=d_{12}+d_{34}=d_{13}+d_{24}=d_{14}+d_{23}.$$
By an indirect way (I used this to construct vector bundles on $\mathbb{P}_3$), I find that $d$ should be a divisor of $d_{12}d_{13}d_{14}$.
I would like to know if this is correct, and if it is true what is a direct proof.

Comment: Have I understood you correctly? For example $1+9=2+8=3+7=10$. But $10$ does not divide $6$ or $9\times8\times7$. You claim such a thing does not happen in your situation?